# how to get the required strings from a text using perl

Tags: perl

Here is the text to trim:

```
/home/netgear/Desktop/WGET-1.13/wget-1.13/src/cmpt.c:388,error,resourceLeak,Resource leak: fr
```

From the above text I need to get the data next to ":". How do I get `388,error,resourceLeak,Resource leak: fr`?

Comment: just use regular expressions

Comment: `my $required_part = q/388,error,resourceLeak,Resource leak: fr/;`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) to separate a string into a list based on a delimiter. In your case the delimiter should be a `:`:

```
my @parts = split ':', $text;
```

As the text you want to extract can also contain a `:`, use the `limit` argument to stop after the first one:

```
my @parts = split ':', $text, 2;
```

`$parts[1]` will then contain the text you wanted to extract. You could also pass the result into a list, discarding the first element:

```
my (undef, $extract) = split ':', $text, 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from [@RobEarl's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1691146/robearl) suggestion of using `split`, you could use a regular expression to do this.

```
my ($match) = $text =~ /^[^:]+:(.*?)$/;
```

Regular expression:

```
^          the beginning of the string
[^:]+      any character except: ':' (1 or more times)
    :      match ':'
(          group and capture to \1:
 .*?       any character except \n (0 or more times)
)          end of \1
$          before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

`$match` will now hold the result of capture group `#1`..

```
388,error,resourceLeak,Resource leak: fr
```